# my UITapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I defined a class named Bubble, and there's a function named CreateBubbleView and I add an tapGestureRecognizer to it.But it is not working. Here's my code.

```
var frame: CGRect = CGRect.zero
var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var bubbleView: UIView!

func CreateBubbleView(arcCenter: CGPoint,radius: CGFloat) {
    bubbleView = UIView(frame: frame)
    bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bubblePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = bubblePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.position = arcCenter
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8, blue: 0.09, alpha: 0.5).cgColor

    bubbleView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleTap))
    bubbleView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

@objc func HandleTap() {
    print(123)
}
```

and in viewController I coded

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bubble_0 = Bubble()
    bubble_0.frame = view.frame
    bubble_0.CreateBubbleView(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 80)
    let bubbleView_0 = bubble_0.bubbleView
    view.addSubview(bubbleView_0!)
}
```

Comment: I am not an expert on IOS, and I cannot help you so much. But I recommend you to explain "it is not working" better if you want to receive some help.

Comment: Exactly, please provide the info what do you mean/ why do you think `its not working`, are you getting any error, what is the behavior, which behavior it should have.. ? Clarify for better impact. thanks in advance- for more info look at [mcve] or / and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: its your Bubble class a UIView subclass?

Comment: What is `Bubble` and what is `bubbleView` ?  Why two views?

Comment: Your `HandleTap()` method should be in camelCase (`handleTap()`). Additionally, you might want to put some "s around 123 so it reads `print("123")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let bubbleView_0 = bubble_0.bubbleView
view.addSubview(bubbleView_0!)
```

I notice you created bubble_0, but only add its bubbleView. bubble_0 will be released(according to ARC). So your tap will no longer have a target. To fix this, you can hold bubble_0 in your view controller.

```
var bubble_0: Bubble!    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bubble_0 = Bubble()
    bubble_0.frame = view.frame
    bubble_0.CreateBubbleView(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 80)
    let bubbleView_0 = bubble_0.bubbleView
    view.addSubview(bubbleView_0!)
}
```

Comment: Thx very much, You fix my problem perfectly. I am a beginner, and I know noting about ARC, can you explain it or recommend some documents, thank you.

Comment: @EthanChu Automatic Reference Counting. There're many blogs that explain how it works.